# Finding the computational complexity of nested loops

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, big-o, time-complexity

I'm not sure if I'm doing these problems correctly so I need someone to tell me if I'm wrong.

```
 for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++ )
```

this is n-0 = n assignment and it's O(g(n)) right?

Okay so know, If I want to get the number of assignments and the O(g(n)) in these questions:

```
 sum = 0;
 for ( i = 1 ; i < n * n ; j ++)
 {
    for ( j = 1 ; j <= n; j ++ )
    {
        sum += j;
    }
}
```

what I did was, sum=0 is one assignment
and the outer loop is n^2 - 1 assignments
and the inner loop is n-1 assignments
and finally the sum is 1 assignment

Therefore, the number of assignments is 2+(n^3+1) which gives O(g(n^3))

In this nested loop :

```
 sum = 0;
 for ( i = 1 ; i <= n; i ++ )
 {
    for ( j = 1 ; j <= 100 ; j++) 
    {
        for ( k = 1 ; k <= n ; k ++ )
        {
            sum += k;
        }
    }
 }
```

What I did was , sum =0 is 1 assignment
then the first loop is 1-n assignments
the second loop 99
the last loop 1-n
and then the sum = 2

So I got 3+(1+n^2) assignments which give me O(g(n^2))

Is there anything wrong with what I just did?

Comment: Not that I see looking it over really quick, though the three-layered nested loop looks a little strange (why iterate through three loops and only work with k?)

Comment: So what was wrong with what I did?

Comment: I don't know why the "g" is in there.  I've seen references to O(f(n)) and O(g(n)) where "f" and "g" are functions of "n".  But here, things like `n^2` and `n^3` _are_ your functions.  So unless "g" has some special new meaning that has been invented after I finished school, I think it doesn't belong.  Just O(n^2) and O(n^3) is what you want.  Other than that, you made some mistakes counting the number of assignments, but the final O(...) answers seem correct.

Comment: More about the mistakes: In the first example, `sum=0` is one assignment, correct.  The outer loop runs `n^2-1` times, correct.  The inner loop runs `n` times, not `n-1`, since the final condition has `<=` instead of `<`.  Finally, why did you add another 1 for the `sum += j`?  When you count the outer and inner loops and multiply them, you're counting the number of times the assignment takes place in the loop; adding an extra 1 just doesn't make sense.  So the total should be `1 + (n^2-1) * n`.  Plus I think your algebra was wrong.  But you got the right answer anyway :)

Comment: @ajb Thanks for clarifying, I have a question though.
If the inner loop runs n times not n-1 then why will the outer loop run n^2-1 and not n^2?

Comment: @rullzrullz Because the outer loop uses `<` and the inner loop uses `<=`.  The outer loop will not execute if `i==n*n`.  This means that the inner loop *will* execute if `j==n` but not if `j==n+1`.

Comment: Thank you ajb, you were very helpful !

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are correct. The only thing might be - sometimes it's important whether it's O(g(n^2)) or O(g(**99***n^2)).
The multiplier becomes not-so-important on large-scaled N values, but at small scales - a constant factor of 99x times the iterations (when not optimized by compiler) might be important.

Comment: Sorry, wrong.  While a program that takes 99 times as long as another is certainly of concern to software people, a constant multiplier has no place in O-notation, which is a mathematical concept.  I'd expect to see a professor mark you down for putting something like that inside your O(...).

Comment: @ajb Well, as a technically, you *are* free to use any amount of constant multipliers and asymptotically smaller terms in big-O notation (`O(n^2) = O(45879n^2 + 55n + 25log n + 13)`), although doing so is pointless (and I agree on the down-marking).

Comment: @ajb Actually, as I recall, `O(2^n) != O(2^(5n))` (well, **something** like that is true, even if that isn't), so the constant multiplier **inside** a function is justified (here we're talking about inside `g`, although, as you said, `g` probably doesn't belong).

Comment: If you care about constant factors, you can use [~ (Tilde)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).

Comment: I was talking about the concept and importance.
If You're to be picky on notations/syntax - O(k*g) would've been the valid one.

Comment: It's not picky.  It has to do with the basic understanding of what big-O notation is, which is saying that some value becomes essentially _proportional_ to the function inside the O, when the argument becomes large enough.  The constant of proportionality doesn't matter.  If you don't understand that O(99*f(n)) = O(f(n)), and the 99 is redundant, then you _don't_ understand the concept.

Comment: Everyone relevant to O-theory understands that O(99*f(n)) = O(f(n)). All what I tried to answer to rullz rullz was that in some cases it's important to know the constant and choose O(7*f(n)) algorithm over O(99*f(n)) one

Comment: @Vlad Agreed. I think their point was that the use of big-O precludes subtleties such as 99x versus 7x. If you want to represent constant factors, and you want to be mathematically accurate about it, you need to use something other than big-O notation.